# Emacs indents after a line starting with a hash in php-mode

Tags: emacs, php, indent

I suspect this has to do something with the C/C++ indenting php-mode indenting is based on, however the hash symbol in PHP just indicates a single-line comment and is not a reason to indent the next line. What can I do about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this through altering php-mode-syntax-table via modify-syntax-entry:

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?# "< b" php-mode-syntax-table)
(modify-syntax-entry ?\n "> b" php-mode-syntax-table)
```

http://emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsSyntaxTable